# Trying to add my model's animation to the animator in Unity but it doesn't work?

Tags: unity, animation, models, animator

I made an animation for a model in blender, then saved and imported it into Unity. In the preview, I can see the animation playing, but when I try to click on 'loop time' or to drag it over to the animator window, it doesn't work. In fact, I can't interact with it, other then drag the model into the scene. I'm not sure whether this is a bug, or if I've missed something with the settings. I am using 2.79

Does anyone know why this is, or has experienced anything similar? Also due to copyright reasons, I cannot upload any content from the game onto here.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with an example asset that will let you share screenshots/info about your situation more freely?

Comment: @DMGregory I actually fiured out the problem, I forgot to attach the animator controller to the model itself XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to drag and drop the animator controller onto the model -_-;

Comment: In future, reproducing the problem in a new empty project before posting will help you spot this type of mistake sooner, and also help you create a minimal complete verifiable example to get answers faster.